# Eventually almost periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Call a function $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ **eventually almost periodic** with period $p > 0$ if for all $x \in [0, p)$, the sequence ${f(x + np)}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges.

Suppose $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and eventually almost periodic of periods $1$ and $a$, where $a$ is irrational and $0 < a < 1$. Define $F: [0, 1) \to \mathbb R$ by $F(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x + n)$.  Is $F$ necessarily constant?

Comment: In your definition, "the sequence converges" in what topology?

Comment: Err, the standard topology on the reals.

Comment: You are referring to the convergence of FUNCTIONS, not reals. What is the topology on the space of your functions?

Comment: f(x+np) is a value sir. Pointwise if you wanna view them as functions. Also I’m editing the question a little.

Comment: Can you give an example where $F$ is not constant?

Comment: Yes, though the construction is a little sketchy, but imagine a series of bump functions that take the value 1 at all points of the form na or n, for n integer. By making the bumps thin out, we can make F converge to 1 at 0 and 0 everywhere else. Hence the edit..

Comment: To be clear, $f$ is e.a.p. with both period $a$ and $1$? As written, it's not exactly clear that that's what you're saying about $a$, though this is the most likely interpretation.

Comment: @user44191 indeed

Comment: Why not adapt the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) construction by quotienting $\mathbb{R}$ with the group generated by integer multiples of $1$ and $a$?

Comment: The resulting function won’t be continuous most likely

Comment: what do you mean by "continuous a. e."? Equivalent to a function which is continuous everywhere?

Comment: Err, the points of continuity are a full measure set. Though as proven below it seems like my naive construction doesn’t work - F has to be constant.

Comment: I guess, your construction allows to get an example of such function which does not have a limit at infinity: choose bumps concentrated on small intervals which are disjoint both modulo 1 and modulo $a$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$F$ must be constant. Consider an $\epsilon>0.$
The sets $$C_N=\{x\in[0,a)\mid |f(x+an)-f(x+am)|\leq \epsilon/3\text{ for all }n,m\geq N\}$$ are closed and cover $[0,a),$ so by the Baire category theorem there is an interval $[c,d]\subset C_N$ for some $0<c<d<a$ and some $N.$ Shrinking the interval $[c,d]$ if necessary we can ensure that
$$f([c,d]+aN) \in [t-\epsilon/3,t+\epsilon/3].\phantom{for all in x in [c,d]}$$ This implies that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}f(x+am)\in [t-2\epsilon/3,t+2\epsilon/3]\text{ for all } x\in[c,d],$$
which gives
$$\phantom{abcdefghi}f(x+an)\in[t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon]\text{ for all }x\in[c,d]\text{ and }n\geq N.$$
But for any $x\in[0,1)$ the sequence $x+n$ lies in the set $[c,d]+a\mathbb N$ infinitely often, giving
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)\in [t-\epsilon, t+\epsilon]\text{ for all }x\in[0,1).\phantom{abc}$$ So $\sup F-\inf F\leq 2\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon,$ which means $F$ is constant.